# Woocommerce thankyou page is not working after checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Today I ran into an interesting issue. After payment thankyou page is not displayed. There is only white screen with menu. You can see it in the screenshot. [thankyou page http://prntscr.com/ofpnuu](http://prntscr.com/ofpnuu)
I tried to create a custom thankyou page and tried to redirect it from the function.php but nothing happened. Then I installed the plugin to create thankyou page but again nothing happened. I have run out of ideas. Can someone tell me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hook below to redirect to the thank you page. Create a thank you page and redirect to that url...

Check the code below:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase' ); 
function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() { 
  global $wp;
  if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.yoururl.com/your-page/' );
    exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep! I've used this hook for creating redirect. But and here is my test page: https://www.nano-jewelry.co.il/thank-you-page-test/ As you can see it works. But when customer bought some item this page doesnt work( Instead of it apeears broken page like on screenshot above.